# Jquery - clearing a counter

Tags: jquery

I need help clearing the counter of this program. I used .empty(); to clear the span, but it wasn't working at all. Thank you

the program works:
- displays the pageX and pageY in an list
- It also counts the clicks
- Clear the results with a button

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    // X and Y position of the cursor
   $("body").click(function(evt){ 
   $('span').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
    var xPos = evt.pageX;
    var yPos = evt.pageY;

    $("#output").append("<li>" + "X:" + xPos + ", Y: " + yPos + "</li>"); 
    }); // end of click function

    //clear list button
    $( "#btnClear" ).click(function() {
    $( "#output").empty();
      event.stopPropagation();
     }); // end clear list


    }); //end of document ready function
    </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="container">
   <h2>Click Away</h2>
  <hr>
    <div id="list"> Counts: <span></span></div>

    <ul id="output">
  <li ></li>
    </ul>
  <button id="btnClear">Clear List</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $output = $("#output"),
        $counter = $('span');

    // X and Y position of the cursor
    $("body").click(function (evt) {
        $counter.html(function (i, val) {
            return val * 1 + 1
        });
        var xPos = evt.pageX;
        var yPos = evt.pageY;

        $output.append("<li>" + "X:" + xPos + ", Y: " + yPos + "</li>");
    }); // end of click function

    //clear list button
    $("#btnClear").click(function (e) {
        $output.empty();
        $counter.empty()
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); // end clear list


}); //end of document ready function
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hZfHn/)

Comment: That works! I don't understand the click(function (e), specifically why the e is there.